# Starting AKSequencer from a specific point

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm using the AudioKit AKSequencer to make a track of midi notes that you can play, pause and stop. The issue I'm having is that when you stop the sequencer playing and restart it without rewinding it picks up exactly where it left off, even if that is midway through a note.

Is it possible to either partially rewind the AKSequencer to the start of the previous note or specify a point in time to start playing from?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the playback with setTime.  Perhaps this could be made better as "playhead time/position" instead of just time.

http://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKSequencer.html#/s:8AudioKit11AKSequencerC7setTimeySdF